# Python, how to substitute Pandas DataFrame values with their row frequency?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
df:

Ind y0   y1  y2  y3  y4  y5  y6 
0   0.7 0.9 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.9 0.9 
1   0.8 0.9 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.9 0.9 
2   0.8 0.9 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.9 1.0
```

I want to replace each value with how many times that value occurs across the row. For the above `DataFrame` the expected result would be:

```
df_1:

Ind  y0  y1  y2  y3  y4  y5 y6 
0     1  3   1   2    2  3  3
1     1  3   1   2    2  3  3
2     1  2   1   2    2  2  1
```

The resulting values in the first row are:

- 0.7 occurs once across the first row so its value is replaced with 1.
- 0.9 occurs three times in the first row, hence the second element of the first row in `df_1` is 3, as well as the 5th and 6th.
- And so on...

**Essentially, the requirement is to count the values row-wise and propagate the counts back to the original positions of the individual values.**

Comment: Did you try to write any code for this yourself?

Comment: Absolutely suspicious why this question is closed.  Can anyone explain it ?

Comment: It would be great for me to understand as well. The question is SOLVED.

Answer (score 4):

There could be a more clever way to do this, but you could use `apply` to apply a function row-wise that maps each value to it's `value_counts()` within that row:

```
def map_value_counts(row):
    vmap = row.value_counts().to_dict()
    return row.replace(vmap)


df.apply(map_value_counts, axis=1)

      y0   y1   y2   y3   y4   y5   y6
Ind                                   
0    1.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  3.0
1    1.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  3.0
2    1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: That works very well, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can `stack` then `groupby` + `transform('size')` using the original index and values as your groups then `unstack` back to your original shape.

```
s = df.stack()
df1 = s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(0), s]).transform('size').unstack(-1)
```

---

```
print(df1)

   y0  y1  y2  y3  y4  y5  y6
0   1   3   1   2   2   3   3
1   1   3   1   2   2   3   3
2   1   2   1   2   2   2   1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`Series.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) together with [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on `axis=1` as follows:

```
df_1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()), axis=1)



print(df_1)

Output:

   y0  y1  y2  y3  y4  y5  y6
0   1   3   1   2   2   3   3
1   1   3   1   2   2   3   3
2   1   2   1   2   2   2   1
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Old School

```
dat = {}
cnt = {}
col = df.columns
for i, *V in df.itertuples():
    for c, v in zip(col, V):
        pointer = cnt.setdefault((i, v), [0])
        pointer[0] += 1
        dat.setdefault(c, {})[i] = pointer
        
pd.DataFrame({c: {i: v[0] for i, v in d.items()} for c, d in dat.items()})

   y0  y1  y2  y3  y4  y5  y6
0   1   3   1   2   2   3   3
1   1   3   1   2   2   3   3
2   1   2   1   2   2   2   1
```